# Adding headers to incoming request in Micronaut filters

Tags: java, micronaut, micronaut-rest

I am writing a service that, for now, will need to implement its own validation of JWT tokens. This will later be handled by a layer before the services.

To do this, I intended to intercept requests using `HttpServerFilter` interface:

```java
@Filter(Filter.MATCH_ALL_PATTERN)
public class SecurityFilter implements HttpServerFilter {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityFilter.class);

    @Override
    public Publisher<MutableHttpResponse<?>> doFilter(final HttpRequest<?> request, final ServerFilterChain chain) {
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return ServerFilterPhase.SECURITY.order();
    }

}
```

The `HttpFilter` interface states:

> To modify the request filters can either wrap it (using io.micronaut.http.HttpRequestWrapper or pass it along the chain as is

So I try to the wrap the request with this class:

```java
final HttpRequestWrapper<?> wrappedRequest = new HttpRequestWrapper<>(request);
// wrappedRequest.getHeaders() Not mutable
// request.mutate().getHeaders() Mutable
// wrappedRequest.mutate().getHeaders() Mutable
```

However, both `mutate` methods above go to the same default implementation in the `HttpRequest` interface:

```java
default MutableHttpRequest<B> mutate() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Request is immutable");
}
```

The documentation states that the filters support *decoration* of requests and *modification* of responses. What is the difference between decorating and modifying here?

The end result I am after is that I want to parse a JWT token, ensure it is valid, and add a field from the token to a new header and retrieve that header from controllers in the following way:

```java
@Get(uri = "/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Optional<Item> findById(@PathVariable("id") final String id, @Header("X-Tenant-Id") final String tenantId) {
    return service.findById(id, tenantId);
}
```

How can I achieve this with Micronaut filters?

Comment: Can't you just do `return chain.proceed(request.mutate().headers(g -> g.add("X-Cheese", "NOW" + UUID.randomUUID())));` in your filter?

Comment: The interface receives `HttpRequest` which is immutable, calling `mutate()` throws an exception.

Comment: Weird...  it worked for me in a test with Micronaut 3.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to add attributes, not headers. Attributes fulfill the same purpose in the end.

```java
@Filter(Filter.MATCH_ALL_PATTERN)
public class SecurityFilter implements HttpServerFilter {

    public static final String TENANT_ID_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "tenantId";

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityFilter.class);

    @Override
    public Publisher<MutableHttpResponse<?>> doFilter(final HttpRequest<?> request, final ServerFilterChain chain) {
        return chain.proceed(request.setAttribute(TENANT_ID_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, "tenantId"));
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return ServerFilterPhase.SECURITY.order();
    }

}
```

And then in a controller:

```java
@Get(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Item> list(@RequestAttribute(SecurityFilter.TENANT_ID_ATTRIBUTE_NAME) final String tenantId) {
    return service.findAll(tenantId);
}
```